# Cannot Get image From Database Django Framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-3.0

I want to create a setting in admin panel which will help me to change the website logo from the admin panel. I create a model for database and it's working and uploading an image to the database + folder. but I cannot get this image to the Website template. when I'm viewing page source image SCR is empty.

**my Model.py**

```
class WebLogo(models.Model):
    Logotitle = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=False)
    SiteLogo = models.ImageField(upload_to='webimages')

def __str__(self):
    return self.Logotitle
```

**my Views.py**

```
from .models import Post,WebLogo


def Display_WebLogo(request):
    # getting all the objects of hotel.
    WebsiteLogo = WebLogo.objects.all()
    return render((request, 'index.html',{'web_images' : WebsiteLogo}))
```

***my project Urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

***my Html Code***

```
  <a href="index.html"><img src="{{ WebLogo.SiteLogo.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="logo">       
  </a>
```

***my app url***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML Code, use 'web_images' not WebLogo like this

```
<a href="index.html"><img src="{{ web_images.0.SiteLogo.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="logo">       
  </a>
```

It looks like {{ data.0 }}. See [Variables and lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups).

Comment: it's didn't work :(( still same when I'm viewing page source there is empty for SCR URL

Comment: thanks ajit it's worked after I add 0 but can you tell me why it's worked after I add 0 between web_images and Sitelogo.url

Answer (score 0):

You should write the required information in the settings.py file.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root

Comment: Zafer what you mean? I didn't understand what means I should write the information. I already did if you mean that I should add Static URL and Meda Root I already did that in settings.py